# Style div (with specific tag), without class or id

Tags: css, attributes

I have like this div, that has no `ID` or `CLASS` attributes:

```
<div data-placement="kolp">
blabla
</div>
```

How can I target that in my CSS ? Maybe some javascript help is needed?

Comment: Target it from whatever it's parent is.

Comment: (Using Chrome)
div[data-placement=kolp]
{
 color: red;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.container > div {
 /* targets your div if it's a direct child of container */
}

.container div {
 /* targets any div that is inside container */
}

div[data-placement=kolp] {
  /* targets any div with the attribute data-placement=kolp */
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JUP87/

Comment: Note: This will target any div that is a direct child of .container.  May need to also use :nth-child() to specify which div it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use attribute-selectors:

```
div[data-placement] {
    /* selects all div elements with the 'data-placement' attribute */
}

/* or */

div[data-placement="kolp"] {
    /* selects all div elements with the 'data-placement' attribute which is equal to 'kolp' */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hHWs3/).

References:

- [CSS Selectors, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).